# How can I access this information in my react state?

Tags: reactjs, state

I'm pretty new to react, now I have this information in my state (shown in the pic), how can I access the message: `"Please enter the valid credential"` in the state?

I've tried `this.state.errors.message` and `this.state.errors[0].message`,
but it seems both are not right, can someone tell me how to access the message? Much appreciated.

[image: Image to see the Error Object]

////////////////////////////////////////////

Hi Chris, thanks very much for your answer.

You are right that the error object is returned from an API, and I have added this to state.

I also tried

this.setState({errors: errorObjFromAPi}, console.log(errors));

the state and be set correctly and the errors can be printed in the console as well.

However, when I tried to render the message in the react component, I used something like 
some html…  {this.state.errors[0].message} , 
then I got an error saying ‘cannot read the property errors[0].message’….

I’m a bit confused as the error object is already sitting in the state, why can’t I access it and render it in the component?

Is the information enough for you to figure out the reason? If not, I’ll provide more specific codes. Again, very much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow postUp17! Please include your data in text format directly in the question instead of linking to external images. `this.state.errors[0].message` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Without more of the code, it's difficult to help.
Have you actually added this to state?  Or has this object just been returned from an API.

If you just done....

```
this.setState({errors: errors});
console.log(this.state.errors[0].message);
```

Then it's most likely that 'set state' hasn't finished before the console.log call as it is async.

Instead, wherever you receive the errors object, try...

```
console.log(errors[0].message);
```

It's also worth noting that set state accepts a callback that can be invoked once set state completes.

E.g.

```
this.setState({errors: errorObjFromAPi}, console.log(errors));  // do a console.log straight after set state has finished.
```

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks very much for your answer, I've updated more information in the question, can you help me to address the problem further? Very much appreciated

Comment: We now need to see some of the code you're using.  Specifically, the component you're trying to render the value in.